# Is there a way to add an index column to a current data frame?

Tags: r, indexing

I have just received a large database and one of the variables needs to be grouped by indices. Specifically, to be indexed every 0.5ish values (e.g. 0 - 0.5, 0.51 - 1, 1.01 - 1.5, ...)

I have tried using cbind (to add the column) with for loops (for each row) and if then statements (to determine the index) to construct another column with the index.

This is the head of the column that I want to index.

```
> x
 2.20
 3.46
 3.30
 1.75
 3.61
 3.95
 0.50
 2.93
 3.00
 3.32
 2.52
 3.52
 2.00
```

I expect the code to look like the following:

```
> x      x_ind
 2.20     5
 3.46     7
 3.30     7
 1.75     4
 3.61     8
 3.95     8
 0.50     1
 2.93     6
 3.00     6
 3.32     7
 2.52     6
 3.52     8
 2.00     4
```

Any help you could give would be super appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `cut` or `findInterval(df$x, c(0.5, 1, 1.5, ..))`

Comment: `df$x_ind <- ceiling(df$x * 2)`